# How can I redirect based on condition in php?

Tags: php, redirect

I have some code that does things based on the condition that is given:

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST"){

  #some kind of redirect to another page

 }

 else{

 #execute  code based on the post data
 #and then redirect to another page after it has finished
 }
```

the header() function doesn't work here for me because it has to be the first thing that the browser sees, is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Assign url in template and do js redirect.

Comment: why can't you move this part of the code to the top of the script before any output is sent? The answer below with header() is the most php-only logical way to do it.

Comment: Fix your code so it is the first thing the browser sees then

Comment: there is actually only php on that page but it kept giving me this error : Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ind.php:2) in /home/ind.php on line 4

Comment: do people just mark you down when they don't know the answer? I dont know how much more clear and simple I could have been. Anyway the JS idea is working for me so I'll use it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use ob_flush?

There might be something else already being outputted to the header?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue and went as far as using jquery/ajax to execute the page and upon .success (jquery/ajax method) assigned window.location.assign('localhost/yadayad.php'). I then discovered its much more simplistic to just echo a JavaScript window.location.assign command within my php file.

```
//user_signup.php
if($_SESSION['user_completed_this_form_already'] == 'complete'){
     echo "<script>window.location.assign('localhost/yadayad.php');</script>";
}
```

this method worked quite nice for me.